# C, Linux: Receiving data from multiple multicast address on same port - how to distinguish them?

Tags: c, linux, multicast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Receving multiple multicast feeds on the same port - C, Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741611/receving-multiple-multicast-feeds-on-the-same-port-c-linux)

I have an application that is receiving data from multiple multicast sources on the same port. I am able to receive the data. However, I am trying to account for statistics of each group (i.e. msgs received, bytes received) and all the data is getting mixed up. Does anyone know how to solved this problem? If I try to look at the sender's address, it is not the multicast address, but rather the IP of the sending machine.

I am using the following socket options:

```
struct ip_mreq mreq;         
mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.1.2.3");         
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;         
setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq));
```

and also:

```
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &reuse, sizeof(reuse));
```

I appreciate any help!!!

Comment: This is an exact repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741611/receving-multiple-multicast-feeds-on-the-same-port-c-linux (without the markup and tagging help from a kindly edit).  Please refrain from making duplicate questions.