# UDP: Listening to the same port for two different multicast streams

Tags: c, linux, udp, multicast

I need to listen to 2 different multicast groups using the same port. `Program A` will listen from `230.0.0.1` and `Program B` from `230.0.0.2`. Both multicast groups use the same `port 2000` and I have no control over it.

When I run my programs I receive both multicast streams in each program, that is both the data packets broadcasted on `230.0.0.1` and `230.0.0.2`. I suspect the problem is due to the common port. This is the code I am using to subscribe to the multicast:

```
if( (sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0 ) {
  perror("socket");
  return -1;
}

if( setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0 ) {
  perror("setsockopt SO_REUSEADDR");
  return -1;
}

memset(&in_addr, 0, sizeof(in_addr));
in_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
in_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
in_addr.sin_port = htons(2000);
if( bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&in_addr, sizeof(in_addr)) < 0 ) {
  perror("bind");
  return -1;
}

memset(&req, 0, sizeof(req));
inet_aton(intfc_ip, &req.imr_interface);
inet_aton("230.0.0.1", &req.imr_multiaddr);
if( setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &req, sizeof(req)) < 0 ) {
  perror("setsockopt IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP");
  return -1;
}

recv()...
```

How can I filter a specific multicast group in each program?

Comment: Have you tried using `recvfrom` instead of `recv`?

Comment: You mean setting the multicast group address in the recvfrom() struct sockaddr parameter? Isn't that supposed to be a source address? I can trace the source addresses of each multicast group with tcpdump, but they might change. I do not produce the data, my interface parameters are the UDP multicast group and port.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C, Linux: Receiving data from multiple multicast address on same port - how to distinguish them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741936/c-linux-receiving-data-from-multiple-multicast-address-on-same-port-how-to-d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change

```
in_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

to

```
inet_aton(<your wanted IP address>, &in_addr.sin_addr.s_addr);
```

you could have more success.

(And if you change your program to work with [`getaddrinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/getaddrinfo.html), you make it future-proof.)

Comment: I just tried, same problem. I replaced "in_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);" with "inet_aton(multicast_addr, &in_addr.sin_addr);". It makes sense to me too, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: As an additional info, I ran tcpdump on the same multicast groups and the only way I've found to only read one of the two groups is by specifying the source address, rather than the IP port (which of course reads both streams).

Comment: Of course you cannot bind to the multicast address. Instead, you should bind to several local addresses (if you have such. If you don't, it won't work...).

Comment: You were right in the first place, I had a problem in my code. This is the right call inet_aton(multicast_addr, &in_addr.sin_addr); Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"connect" might be what you need after all.  Typically, for connecting TCP sockets, the man page also suggests that it can be used for filtering out UDP packets from other addresses:

From the man page posted [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect):

> If the socket sockfd is of type SOCK_DGRAM then addr is the address to
>   which datagrams are sent by default, **and the only address from which
>   datagrams are received.**

Comment: This doesn't work, I added the connect() and don't receive any packet at all:memset(&mc_addr, 0, sizeof(mc_addr));
  mc_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  mc_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(multicast_addr);
  mc_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  printf("Connecting...\n");
  connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&mc_addr, sizeof(mc_addr))

Comment: Selbie, I think this makes my question more specific at least. connect() is what I want as per the man pages, except I can't make it work on my system. I will post a separate question.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm out of ideas at this point.  I stand by my original answer of using recvmsg to filter out unwanted packets.

Comment: Right, but I can to that more easily by looking at the contents of each app message, which I have to parse anyway. I was looking for an easier solution but apparently it's not that simple.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with socket code is that "recvfrom" will only give you the source address from where the packet was sent from.  It doesn't tell you the IP address of where the packet was sent to.  You want to be able to inspect the destination address of the UDP packet so you can filter out packets that were sent to multicast IP addresses you are not interested in.

There is a socket option you can set followed by the use of "recvmsg" instead of recv or recvfrom to get the destination IP adddress the packet was sent to.

1) Use setsockopt with IP_PKTINFO to enable getting the destination IP address passed up to the app level for data received on the socket.

```
int enable = 1;
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP , IP_PKTINFO , &enable, sizeof(enable));
```

2) Use recvmsg instead of recvfrom (or recv) to get the destination address the UDP packet was sent to.  I have a helper function called "recvfromex" that wraps recvmsg and mirrors the functionality of recvfrom - expect it has an extra parameter for the caller to get the destination IP of the packet.

It's a bit windy to post - but you can look at my C++ code from my github project and take what you need.

Look at the recvfromex function [here](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/master/networkutils/recvfromex.cpp)

More code sample for the setsockopt call [here](https://github.com/jselbie/stunserver/blob/master/networkutils/stunsocket.cpp) (look for the function "EnablePktInfo" on how to use the setsockopt call with IP_PKTINFO). Also contains extensions for IPV6 and BSD.

Comment: Ideally I want to filter the stream in the kernel, not by checking the address in the application code. Is there a way to tell the kernel/UDP stack that I am only interested in packets for a specific group **and** port, rather than just the port?

Comment: What if you configured your network settings such that you had two IP addresses for your NIC?  Then instead of binding your socket to INADDR_ANY, you bind to one of the specific IP addresses (and bind to the other address in the other program).  I know this will definitely work if you have two NICs on the same box (each with a unique IP), but I'm not certain if it will work if you multihome your machine using only one NIC.

Comment: ok, my question is whether the linux kernel can do the job. Or, in other words, is there any way to insure that only a specific multicast group is delivered to an application on Linux (regardless of other subscribed multicasts that are being streamed through the same port).

Comment: I know if you call "connect" on a UDP socket, subsequent "send" calls will direct packets to the address passed to connect. I know on Windows, this will also filter out traffic from other addresses in the "recv" call as well.  I'm not sure if Linux does recv side filtering on UDP sockets based on connect.  But it's worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

(from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20919920/3102264) of [Receving multiple multicast feeds on the same port - C, Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741611/receving-multiple-multicast-feeds-on-the-same-port-c-linux))

The [ip(7) manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) describe a possible solution :

> IP_MULTICAST_ALL (since Linux 2.6.31)
>                 This option can be used to modify the delivery policy of
>                 multicast messages to sockets bound to the wildcard INADDR_ANY
>                 address.  The argument is a boolean integer (defaults to 1).
>                 If set to 1, the socket will receive messages from all the
>                 groups that have been joined globally on the whole system.
>                 Otherwise, it will deliver messages only from the groups that
>                 have been explicitly joined (for example via the
>                 IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP option) on this particular socket.

Then you can activate the filter to receive messages of joined groups using :

```
int mc_all = 0;
if ((setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_ALL, (void*) &mc_all, sizeof(mc_all))) < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt() failed");
}
```