# UDP connect() and recv() on Linux

Tags: c, linux, udp

According to the connect(2) man pages

> If  the  socket sockfd is of type SOCK_DGRAM then serv_addr is the address to which datagrams are sent by default, **and the only address from which datagrams are received**.  If the socket is of type SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_SEQPACKET, this call attempts to  make a connection to the socket that is bound to the address specified by serv_addr.

I am trying to filter packets from two different multicast groups that are being broadcasted on the same port and I thought connect() would have done the job but I can't make it work. In facts when I add it to my program I don't receive any packet. More info in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480132/udp-listening-to-the-same-port-for-two-different-multicast-streams).

This is how I set the connect parameters:

```
memset(&mc_addr, 0, sizeof(mc_addr));
mc_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
mc_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(multicast_addr);
mc_addr.sin_port = htons(multicast_port);
printf("Connecting...\n");
if( connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&mc_addr, sizeof(mc_addr)) < 0 ) {
  perror("connect");
  return -1;
}

printf("Receiving...\n");
while( (len = recv(sd, msg_buf, sizeof(msg_buf), 0)) > 0 )
  printf("Received %d bytes\n", len);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your program (probably) has the following problems:

- you should be using bind() instead of connect(), and
- you're missing setsockopt(..., IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, ...).

Here's an example program that receives multicasts. It uses recvfrom(), not recv(), but it's the same except you also get the source address for each received packet.

To receive from multiple multicast groups, you have *three* options.

**First option**: Use a separate socket for each multicast group, and bind() each socket to a *multicast address*. This is the simplest option.

**Second option**: Use a separate socket for each multicast group, bind() each socket INADDR_ANY, and use a socket filter to filter out all but a single multicast group.

Because you've bound to INADDR_ANY, you may still get packets for other multicast groups. It is possible to filter them out using the kernel's socket filters:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/filter.h>

/**
 * Adds a Linux socket filter to a socket so that only IP
 * packets with the given destination IP address will pass.
 * dst_addr is in network byte order.
 */
int add_ip_dst_filter (int fd, uint32_t dst_addr)
{
    uint16_t hi = ntohl(dst_addr) >> 16;
    uint16_t lo = ntohl(dst_addr) & 0xFFFF;

    struct sock_filter filter[] = {
        BPF_STMT(BPF_LD + BPF_H + BPF_ABS, SKF_NET_OFF + 16), // A <- IP dst high
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K, hi, 0, 3),        // if A != hi, goto ignore
        BPF_STMT(BPF_LD + BPF_H + BPF_ABS, SKF_NET_OFF + 18), // A <- IP dst low
        BPF_JUMP(BPF_JMP + BPF_JEQ + BPF_K, lo, 0, 1),        // if A != lo, goto ignore
        BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, 65535),                     // accept
        BPF_STMT(BPF_RET + BPF_K, 0)                          // ignore
    };

    struct sock_fprog fprog = {
        .len = sizeof(filter) / sizeof(filter[0]),
        .filter = filter
    };

    return setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, &fprog, sizeof(fprog));
}
```

**Third option**: use a single socket to receive multicasts for all multicast groups.

In that case, you should do an IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP for each of the groups. This way you get all packets on a single socket.

However, you need extra code to determine which multicast group a received packet was addressed to. To do that, you have to:

- receive packets with **recvmsg()** and read the IP_PKTINFO or equivalent ancillary data message. However, to make recvmsg() give you this message, you first have to
- enable reception of IP_PKTINFO ancillary data messages with setsockopt().

The exact thing you need to do depends on IP protocol version and OS. Here's how I did it (IPv6 code not tested): [enabling PKTINFO](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/source/browse/trunk/system/BDatagram_unix.c#200) and [reading the option](http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/source/browse/trunk/system/BDatagram_unix.c#422).

Here's a simple program that receives multicasts, which demonstrates the first option (bind to multicast address).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#define MAXBUFSIZE 65536

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 4) {
        printf("Usage: %s <group address> <port> <interface address>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    int sock, status, socklen;
    char buffer[MAXBUFSIZE+1];
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    struct ip_mreq imreq;

    // set content of struct saddr and imreq to zero
    memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    memset(&imreq, 0, sizeof(struct ip_mreq));

    // open a UDP socket
    sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("socket failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    // join group
    imreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    imreq.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[3]);
    status = setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
    (const void *)&imreq, sizeof(struct ip_mreq));

    saddr.sin_family = PF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
    saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
    status = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (status < 0) {
        perror("bind failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    // receive packets from socket
    while (1) {
        socklen = sizeof(saddr);
        status = recvfrom(sock, buffer, MAXBUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, &socklen);
        if (status < 0) {
            printf("recvfrom failed!\n");
            return 1;
        }

        buffer[status] = '\0';
        printf("Received: '%s'\n", buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not asking for a basic UDP program, I need to filter different multicast groups that are being broadcasted on the same port. For the complete version of my program pls check the link I mentioned in the question.

Comment: This is a great answer, it saved my life !

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that multicast packets are sent *to* a multicast address, not *from* a multicast address.
connect() will allow (or not) packets received from a nominated address.

To configure your socket to receive multicast packets you need to use one of two socket options:

- IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, or
- IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP

The former allows you to specify a multicast address, the latter allows you to specify a multicast address and source address of the sender.

This can be done using something like the following:

```
struct ip_mreq groupJoinStruct;
unsigned long groupAddr = inet_addr("239.255.0.1");

groupJoinStruct.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = groupAddr;
groupJoinStruct.imr_interface.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;   // or the address of a specific network interface
setsockopt( yourSocket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &groupJoinStruct );
```

(error handling omitted for brevity)

To stop receiving multicast packets for this group address, use the socket options:

- IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP, or
- IP_DROP_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP

Note that a socket can have multiple multicast memberships. But, as the multicast address is the destination address of the packet, you need to be able to grab the destination address of the packet to be able to distinguish between packets for different multicast addresses.

To grab the destination address of the packet you'll need to use `recvmsg()` instead of `recv()` or `recvfrom()`. The destination address is contained within the IPPROTO_IP message level, of type DSTADDR_SOCKOPT.
As @Ambroz Bizjak has stated, you'll need to set the `IP_PKTINFO` socket option to be able to read this information.

---

Other things to check are:

- Is multicast supported in your kernel? Check for the existence of /proc/net/igmp to ensure it's been enabled.
- Has multicast been enable on your network interface? Check for "MULTICAST" listed when you run `ifconfig` on your interface
- Does your network interface support multicast? Historically not all have. If not you may be able to get around this by setting your interface to promiscuous mode. e.g. `ifconfig eth0 promisc`

Comment: Andrew, I appreciate the clear explanation but as I commented before I would like to know why the kernel can not filter the multicast packets for me. I do add membership (in facts I think without this option set the program will not receive any packet) but the problem is that if another process subscribe to the same feed broadcasting on the same port I will start receiving both multicasts.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as all the SENDING sockets are bound to the multicast address in question with `bind`.  The address you specify in `connect` is matched against the SOURCE address of received packets, so you want to ensure that all packets have the same (multicast) SOURCE AND DESTINATION.

Comment: Chris, I don't have control over the sending program but I do know the source address from tcpdump or the ancillary data. I have already tried to call connect() with the multicast address as I explained in my question but I don't receive any packet that way. Are you suggesting to call connect() using the source unicast address? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Chris: Note that the source address is the unicast address of the host sending the packet. connect() probably works as documented - you can use it to filter out a single unicast source address. On the other  hand, the multicast address is the *destination* address of the packet.

Comment: @Robert: seeing that the ancillary data gives you the destination (multicast) address, isn't this solved?

Comment: @Ambroz: I don't want to filter packets in the application code. I am already doing that by looking at the application data in each packet. I was looking for a way to instruct the kernel to do the filtering. I find hard to understand how the kernel can not dispatch packets for a specific multicast to each socket.

Comment: @Robert: you don't need any filtering. Just use multiple sockets, and associate each socket with its own multicast address (IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP). I've mentioned this in my answer, and also it's kind of obvious?

Comment: @Robert: also you may need to set the SO_REUSEADDR option on the sockets before you bind them, or bind() may fail with EADDRINUSE.

Comment: Ambroz, that doesn't work. If another process subscribe to a different group on the same port, I will get both multicasts in each process.

Comment: In any case the original question is about UDP connect() and what's on the Linux man page.

Comment: @Robert: Oh, sorry, I didn't know that the kernel also reports multicast groups that haven't been joined on a given socket. In that case, I think the only solution is to set a socket filter to each socket. I'll add details to my answer shortly.

Comment: @Robert: here you go, I've added code for the socket filter (tested).

Comment: @Robert: turns out that you can also just bind() to a multicast address, and the kernel will give you only packets for this multicast group.

Answer (score 0):

`bind(2)` each socket to the address of the respective multicast group and port instead of `INADDR_ANY`. That would do the filtering for you.

Comment: True, that would work. But the question is about connect() and what's in the man page.